# Is there any function to calculate the p-Schatten norm of a matrix?

Tags: matrix

For $p \in [1, \infty)$, the $p$-Schatten norm of a matrix $A$ is defined as
$\|A\|_p = Tr(\left|A\right|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$, where $\left|A\right| = (A^* A)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Is there any function to calculate those norms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Total[SingularValueList[A]^p]^(1/p)
```

or

```
Power[Tr[MatrixPower[A\[Transpose] . A, p/2]], 1/p]
```

Comment: The first one is a bit faster.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not use `Norm[...,p]` on the `SingularValueList`?

Comment: Bevause `Norm` is slower.